# Dynamically change image of a Listview/ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` that I use to display file/folder hierarchy inside my application. I'm using a custom layout with  an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. I want to change the image of the `ImageView` according to `TextView` text is ether folder or file. Can I do this without using a custom `ArrayAdapter` or if I have to use a custom `ArrayAdapter` how can I change `ImageView` icon in the runtime.?

Comment: You will have to write a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a custom adapter any time you need more than one variable item per entry in the list (i.e. in your case you have two, the `ImageView` and the `TextView`).  Changing data at runtime is most easily achieved by calling [`ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can check that in getView function of custom adapter and set imageview according to the textview.
see [this example](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) for custom array adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageView.setImageResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) method.

Comment: can I use it even my imageview is in diffrent layout.?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `getView()` method in your custom adapter class.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View newRowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;


    if(newRowView == null)
    {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    newRowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.my_list, parent,false); 
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.name = (TextView) newRowView.findViewById(R.id.textInList);

    viewHolder.image = (ImageView) newRowView.findViewById(R.id.iconInList);

    newRowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) newRowView.getTag();

    }


    viewHolder.image.setImageDrawable(textImages[position]);

    viewHolder.name.setText(names[position]);

    return newRowView; 
}



static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView name;
    ImageView image;

}
```

Here `textImages` & `names` are the arrays which I passed to the custom adapter from the activity class.

***This is the most memory efficient and fast way.***